# When inequality becomes equality: $\Re(x^*Ax)^2+\Im(x^*Ax)^2\leq\|Ax\|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Given any $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, I have the following theorem from few papers which don't provide the proof

$$\Re(x^*Ax)^2+\Im(x^*Ax)^2\leq\|Ax\|^2,$$

where $x\in\{x\in\mathbb{C}^n: \|x\|=1\}$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is the second norm.

I am interested in when the above inequality becomes equality?

---

Lets rewrite $\Re(x^*Ax)=\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $\Im(x^*Ax)=\frac{A-A^*}{2i}$, then

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
(x^*\frac{A+A^*}{2}x)^2+(x^*\frac{A-A^*}{2i}x)^2&\leq x^*A^*Ax, \\
(x^*Ax+x^*A^*x)^2+(x^*Ax-x^*A^*x)^2&\leq4x^*A^*Ax,\\
|x^*Ax|^2+|x^*A^*x|^2&\leq2x^*A^*Ax
\end{split}
\end{equation}

from the last part I got a feeling that the equality will be achieved only when $x^*A^*Ax$ is a singular value of $A$, so maybe there are only $n$ unit vectors $x$ such that the above inequality becomes equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
&\left(\Re(x^*Ax)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*Ax)\right)^2\\
&=|x^\ast Ax|^2\\
&=|\langle Ax,x\rangle|^2\\
&\le\|Ax\|_2^2\|x\|_2^2\\
&=\|Ax\|_2^2.\\
\end{aligned}

Comment: ok, then the equality is achieved only when $x$ is eigenvector of $A$. thanks